# css: impossible to grow the pricing page

Tags: html, css

check out this static tempalte from https://github.com/kybernetyk/medstime/tree/master/src/medstime/static

the page that I'm having trouble with is

https://github.com/kybernetyk/medstime/blob/master/src/medstime/static/plans-pricing.html

Inside the `<aside>` tag, when you try to increase the number of items, the `<div class="grid">`
 stays fixed in height and size!

I've literally tried everything from setting height on it but it is impossible to grow the container as I add more content inside it.

Comment: you're going to have to post a fiddle or something, at least the relevant html and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize in advance if you have already tried this. But I looked in the CSS code under saas-common.css and found this:

```
.grid aside {
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 110px;
    text-align: right;
}

.grid aside li {
    line-height: 51px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.grid .sections {
    width: 782px;
    height: 511px;
    background: url(../images/bg-grid-box.png) no-repeat left top;
    float: right;
}

.grid section {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 509px;
}
```

Looks like there are some fixed heights under the grid div. You could try overriding with !important.

A few things to try from there:

```
min-height: 500px;
height:auto;
```

Then,

```
overflow:hidden;
```

And if all else fails,

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: where do I place the min height and the overflow properties?

Comment: That's the issue, and I suggest experimenting a bit with this. First try replacing where it says height to min-height because height is a restraint. Overflow might have something to do with it too. If you possibly put overflow:visible; in the <.grid aside> div then that might show any hidden content. It's not good that this website has a fixed height and width because it doesn't really let you expand on it. But I suggest making the height values min-height instead. If you post a JSFiddle or some online version of your code then maybe we can play around with it a bit.